# javascript split method comma but without double quotes

Tags: javascript

I have a string and want to split it by comma `,` but my string also has `","` which I want ignored, so in short I want to split only where there's `,` without double quotes.

This is the code I'm testing it with

```js
function splitByCommas(str) {
    return str.split(/,(?=(?:[:""]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/);
}
```

Results from the function above:

`console.log(splitByCommas('gango.cs.{"test","asfasf"},ratings.eq.5,name.eq.kings}'));`

What the function outputs `[ 'gango.cs.{"test"', '"asfasf"}', 'ratings.eq.5', 'name.eq.kings}' ]`

My desired output `[ 'gango.cs.{"test","asfasf"}', 'ratings.eq.5', 'name.eq.kings}' ]`

Anyone might have a hint on how to get my desired output?

Comment: Why so complicated? I'd split simply by a comma not preceded by quote and not followed by quote: `/(?<!"),(?!")/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/(?<!"),(?!")/` regex.

I've tested and confirmed the following code is working.

```js
function splitByCommas(str) {
    return str.split(/(?<!"),(?!")/);
}
```